# How is TN-CS safer than TN-C

Tags: grounding, wiring, power-grid

Why not just run two PEN wires?

Can you explain a situation in which having wires with separate and designated PE, N functions is *safer* than having two PEN wires? Or is that basically where all of the additional safety comes from?

I know that PEN (and N) is "intended to carry current," but what is the problem with that? It's the voltage difference that kills and both PE and N should be grounded at the same point -- the point of their separation (and PEN at the transformer).

Doesn't adding more grounding points (in case of TN-CS as compared to TN-C) just increase the chance of a good path between a person and the neutral at the transformer?

I do not know anything about electricity. My EE education was brief, poor and in the distant past. Please be gentle with your explanations (diagrams preferred). Thank you!